# Are there any OS X hypervisors that allow nested virtualisation?

Tags: linux, virtualization, virtual-machine

I am preparing for the RHCSA exam and am using a CentOS 7 VM to practice. One of the objectives is to be able to configure a KVM VM using Virtual Machine Manager and hence my CentOS VM's emulated CPU needs to have VT-x support, which I need to be able to pass through from the host (my host is a Mac laptop with an Intel CPU).

Unfortunately, I am using VirtualBox and VirtualBox [does not support nested virtualisation](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/4032) so I was wondering if there are any alternatives (preferably free) for OS X that would allow me to practice KVM virtualisation on my CentOS VM.